# AMP page not loading correctly on IE11

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP page here:

https://www.homeprotect.co.uk/

The page is built using AMP and is loading perfectly on Chrome, Edge, Firefox but not in IE11

In IE11 the amp-mega-menu doesn't load correctly nor does the amp-sidebar

I have debugged it and it appears that the amp-mega-menu isn't having it's relevant stylesheet loaded

Comment: IE is no longer supported. Check links [here](https://blog.amp.dev/2021/07/20/deprecation-of-internet-explorer-support/) and [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/34453)

Comment: Thank you @phuzi, that's helpful. Did you want to add it as an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately IE is no longer supported and was deprecated some time ago.

For further info see the [deprecation notice](https://blog.amp.dev/2021/07/20/deprecation-of-internet-explorer-support/) and the [Github issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/34453)